# Invoking class method in Generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code:

```
private void StartTask<T>(string parameter)
{
    dynamic instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameter);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.DoCompare());
}
```

This does not work and the "DoCompare()" method does not get called...How do I call a method in a class with parameters in a generic type method?

Class I am initiating:

```
public class Something {
     private string _parameter;

     public Something(string parameter) {
     _parameter = parameter;
     }

     public void DoCompare(){
      //Do longrunning task
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: Removed constraint BaseClass5 because of confusion

**EDIT2**: I get: A first chance exception of type

> 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'

**EDIT3:**

This seems to work, the issue seems to be Task.Factory.StartNew:

```
private void StartTaskAwesomium<T>() where T 
{
    dynamic instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), parameter);
    instance.Test();
}
```

Comment: Too many variables, and too many possible assumptions about them, to be able to give a definitive answer. Show us more about the class you're instantiating.

Comment: why `dynamic` instead of `T` ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not called? You're making it run asynchronously. Try setting a breakpoint inside DoCompare

Comment: Dennis, yes I am sure. I added breakpoint and the method is never reached.

Comment: Raphael: Because it doesn't compile with T.

Comment: Unless you constrain it to a type that declares 'DoComapre' there's no way to compile it with T.

Comment: This looks like a really big mistake - why doesn't `Something` implement an interface that `StartTask` can constrain itself to?  Also, the fact that `StartTask` is already geared towards creating objects of type `Something` (unless every class you create has a constructor that takes a `string`) is a giant red flag.

Comment: It does have a interface, I just didn't include it here. It's funny how people always criticize other people code on SO without knowing all the facts. If you don't know the answer, stay quiet.

Comment: Wtf does having an interface have to do with anything? How is that a "useful" fact? lol

Comment: I tried to run similar code and instance.DoCompare() threw a RuntimeBinderException...

Comment: If I constrain T to something and use that instead of dynamic, it works fine. The problem is with dynamic somehow or the combination dynamic/Tasks. Hopefully someone else can pick up on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to wrap the creation of the class in the Task itself like this:

```
private void StartTask<T>(string connectionId) where T : BaseClass5
{          
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        dynamic instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), connectionId);
        instance.DoCompare();
    });
}
```

Comment: So wrapping this in a lambda expression really does make a difference, I wonder if anyone has an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

In theory your code should work, but it is a "*fire-and-forget*" pattern, meaning it will be executed *sometime*, but you have no control over that or can check if it actually was executed or if there was an exception.
Maybe change it to:

```
private async void StartTask<T>(string parameter) where T : BaseClass5
{
    BaseClass5 instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameter);
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.DoCompare());
}
```

No need for the `dynamic` as because of your generic constraint you know that `T` must be `BaseClass5` or based on it.

Or return the task to `await` (or `task.Wait()`) it elsewhere:

```
private Task StartTask<T>(string parameter)
{
    T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameter);
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.DoCompare());
}
```

Comment: BaseClass5 was just a constraint, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: new() only works if it's parameterless, which it is not. Hence the need of Activator.

Comment: Then please show how `BaseClass5` or the actual type you supply looks like, but the `dynamic` is definitely not needed...

Comment: You could have `T instance` instead of `BaseClass5 instance` no ? Just keep it generic...

Comment: Updated question with the supplied class and method.

Comment: Which version did you try?

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void StartTask<T>(string parameter)
{
    dynamic instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameter);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {instance.DoCompare();});
}
```

This seems to work.